# Primes satisfying a certain property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find all positive integer pairs $(p,m)$ where $p \geq 3$ is a prime and:
> $$2(p-3)! + 1 = p^m$$

**What I Tried**: Firstly what I noticed is,
$$2 \equiv (p-2)(p-1)\pmod p$$
$$\implies 2(p-3)!+1 \equiv (p-1)!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
Where the last line holds by Wilson's Theorem.

But for the question, this information looks very unnecessary, since we already have $m \geq 1$, so I am not sure how to proceed further.
And inspection gives us $(p,m) = (3,1), (5,1), (7,2)$ are some solutions. I checked some for $p > 7$, and I doubt more to exist.

Could anyone help me here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For $1\le n\le 10^4$ , $2n!+1$ is only a perfect power for $n=4$:

Comment: @Peter could you tell how u got that result?

Comment: Just brute force with PARI/GP

Comment: @Peter ohh, a mathematical proof would have been better :)

Comment: "Generalized Wilson primes of order three" are primes are primes $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $2(p-3)!+1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime#Wilson_primes_of_order_n See also https://oeis.org/A128666 (although it doesn't help a lot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already checked the solutions for the primes $p \le 7$. For $p \gt 7$, we have $2(p - 3)! + 1 \gt p^2$, so we just need to check for any $m \gt 2$. Rearranging your equation gives that

$$2(p-3)! = p^{m} - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The [lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) states that, if $m$ is odd, then

$$\nu_2(p^{m} - 1) = \nu_2(p - 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

while for $m$ being even we have

$$\nu_2(p^{m} - 1) = \nu_2(p - 1) + \nu_2(p + 1) + \nu(m) - 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

It's simple to show, as I've done, you've indicated, and [Peter's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845732/primes-satisfying-a-certain-property#comment10323382_4845732) states, that there are no solutions for $p = 11$ and $p = 13$. Consider any prime $p \ge 17$. Since each odd integer $\ge 3$ occurs between two consecutive powers of $2$, there's a corresponding integer $k \ge 4$ where

$$2^{k} \lt p \lt 2^{k+1} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using just the powers of $2$ among the factors of $(p - 3)!$, and the non-powers of $2$ less than $16$ (i.e., $6$, $10$, $12$ and $14$, for a total of $5$), we get

$$\nu_{2}(2(p - 3)!) \ge 1 + 5 + (1 + 2 + \ldots + k - 1) = 6 + \frac{(k - 1)k}{2} \ge 3k \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $\nu_2(p - 1) \le k$, this shows using \eqref{eq2A} that there are no solutions for odd $m$. Thus, consider $m$ being even. Note $m \lt p$, so $\nu(m) \le k$. Also, one of $p - 1$ or $p + 1$ has just one factor of $2$, with the other having at most $k + 1$ factors of $2$, so the RHS of \eqref{eq3A} becomes

$$\nu_2(p - 1) + \nu_2(p + 1) + \nu(m) - 1 \le 1 + (k + 1) + k - 1 = 2k + 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

However, this contradicts \eqref{eq5A}, so \eqref{eq3A} doesn't hold.

This shows there are no more solutions to \eqref{eq1A} for $p \ge 3$ other than the ones you've shown. More generally, since the solution above for $p \ge 17$ applies to *all* such odd integers, and [Peter's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845732/primes-satisfying-a-certain-property#comment10323382_4845732) indicates there are no solutions among the smaller values, this means there are no additional solutions for any integer $p \ge 3$.

Comment: Nice solution @John Omielan, LTE kind of just slipped out of my mind. Another question,  you could claim point (4) from bertrand's postulate isn't it?

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for the compliment. My $(4)$ is just that *every* odd integer is between two consecutive powers of $2$. It doesn't have anything to with Bertrand's postulate as I'm not stating, or using, that there's at least one $p$ for each $k$ or anything else similar to that. Note also my generalization at the end re: no solutions for all odd integers. Instead, I used that characterization so I could determine explicit bounds on various $\nu_2$ values, to then use those bounds to get the contradictions which I used to show there are no other solutions than the ones you stated.

Comment: Oh okay I see it now thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous You're welcome, and I'm glad you now see it. I also appreciate your feedback, as I've now updated my answer to explain in more detail about $(4)$ since, otherwise, additional people reading that part may also have issues understanding it.